I can't make multiple typewriters start after the former finishes ( react, tailwind css)
I am trying to add 3 typewriter in three different div
each of the typewriters are in separate div
how can i make the second typewriter start after the first finishes and the third to start after the second finishes
import React from "react";
import AI from "../images/AI.png";
import Typewriter from "typewriter-effect";
const Home = () => {
return (
<div
  className="bg-cover bg-center min-h-screen min-w-screen flex flex-row-reverse items-center"
  style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${AI})` }}
>
  <div className=" w-1/2">
    <div className=" text-3xl">
      {" "}
      <Typewriter
        options={{
          strings: ["Transform your ideas into"],
          autoStart: true,
          loop: true,
        }}
      />
    </div>
    <div className="text-3xl">
      {" "}
      <Typewriter
        options={{
          strings: ["breathtaking creations with"],
          autoStart: true,
          loop: true,
          pauseFor: 3000,
        }}
      />
    </div>
    <div className="text-4xl font-bold">
      {" "}
      <Typewriter
        options={{
          strings: ["Generative AI"],
          autoStart: true,
          loop: false,
        }}
      />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
 );
 };

 export default Home;

